# How to fix "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../clientAndAPi/follow' "

Tags: javascript, heroku, webpack

I am trying to push my java app to heroku using `git push heroku master`. When it got to creating a bundle.js file from my `webpack.config.js`, I got this error -->

> "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../clientAndAPi/follow' in '/tmp/build_3ee67cfe22a500174d8ca2c8820a8a21/sneakysneaksGUI/src/components/Landing'"

The output should be a compiled `bundle.js` without errors
I am trying to push my java app to heroku using git push heroku master. When it got to creating a bundle.js file from my webpack.config.js, I got this error -->

> "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../clientAndAPi/follow' in '/tmp/build_3ee67cfe22a500174d8ca2c8820a8a21/sneakysneaksGUI/src/components/Landing'"

I tried changing the way I imported the files (`import follow from --> const follow = require..`) This led to the same error. 
I also tried changing from module.exports in the follow.js file to export default

```
//imports in Landing.jsx

const follow = require('../../clientAndAPi/follow');
//import follow from '../../clientAndAPi/follow'; // function to hop multiple links by "rel"
```

```
//both ways produce problem
//follow.js
module.exports = function follow(api, rootPath, relArray) {
    const root = api({
        method: 'GET',
        path: rootPath
    });

    return relArray.reduce(function(root, arrayItem) {
        const rel = typeof arrayItem === 'string' ? arrayItem : arrayItem.rel;
        return traverseNext(root, rel, arrayItem);
    }, root);

    function traverseNext (root, rel, arrayItem) {
        return root.then(function (response) {
            if (hasEmbeddedRel(response.entity, rel)) {
                return response.entity._embedded[rel];
            }

            if(!response.entity._links) {
                return [];
            }

            if (typeof arrayItem === 'string') {
                return api({
                    method: 'GET',
                    path: response.entity._links[rel].href
                });
            } else {
                return api({
                    method: 'GET',
                    path: response.entity._links[rel].href,
                    params: arrayItem.params
                });
            }
        });
    }

    function hasEmbeddedRel (entity, rel) {
        return entity._embedded && entity._embedded.hasOwnProperty(rel);
    }
};
```

```
//webpack.config.js
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  //TODO -- Change to the real location of app.js 
  entry: './sneakysneaksGUI/src/index.js',
  devtool: 'sourcemaps',
  cache: true,
  mode: 'development',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: './src/main/resources/static/built/bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: path.join(__dirname, '.'),
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-flow"]
          }
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
  }
};
```

This currently gives an error.
The output should be a compiled bundle.js without errors